How to retain query parameters in URL for HTMX hx-post request
I'm building a frontend using HTMX and I've encountered a problem with dynamically setting URLs for hx-post requests while retaining query parameters. Here's the scenario:
I have a base URL such as example.com/project?id=someid. I need to make an hx-post request to example.com/project/collections?id=someid, but I'm unsure how to append to the URL path and retain the query parameter effectively using HTMX.
Currently, I have:
<form hx-post="/collections"></div>

However, this results in a request to http://example.localhost/collections, and I receive a 404 (Not Found) error because the id parameter is missing. I tried using all combinations of trailing slashes and none were giving me the result I need
How can I append the /collections path to the base URL while preserving the query parameter (id=someid) when using HTMX? Is there a way to do this directly in the HTML attribute, or do I need to use JavaScript to modify the hx-post attribute before the request is made (which I'd like to avoid)?
What is the HTML/ Hypermedia approach to such a common problem? Most of my frontend experience is using React and similar frameworks so my whole paradigm has shifted.
I initially wanted to have url structure of
/project/<id> and /project/<id>/collections

When parsing the html template and returning it to the client, can you include the query in it? Something like: <form hx-post="/collections?id={{ .MyQuery }}"></div>. Edit: Btw, this would also work in the path parameter ("/project/{{ .Id }}/collections").

I can do something like that yeah. Was hoping there could be a cleaner approach like the things I tried.

I would also do it the way @FirstOne suggests. Just have some_id in the context of the base template and you can easily use it in the collections/ endpoint.
